# Ionic 2 - how to open special page when tap on push notification?

Tags: ionic2

I know that I can pass data in payload, but how to realize an opening special page when tap on push notificaton?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`DeepLinker`](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/navigation/DeepLinker/) of ionic2, it is similar as route of angular2. In app module, you can set it like:

`imports: [
   IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp, {}, {
     links: [
      { component: SomeDetailPage, name: 'SomeDetail', segment: 'some/detail/:id' }
    ]
  })
 ]`